# Audit Trail in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any way to view Audit Trail in Marketing Cloud? If not, anything we can do to set up one?

Is this data captured in some object which can be accessed vi API?

Comment: An audit trail of what?

Comment: Of the users who log in, any changes configuration that they do etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the April 2019 release a new 'Basic Audit Trail' and 'Advanced Audit Trail' feature was introduced

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_platform_audit_logging.htm&type=0

This will allow you to extract audit trail information via a data extract activity or via the API

You can view a comparison of the difference between the two audit trails here 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_audit_trail.htm&type=5

You need to enable the Audit Trail Logging feature before these extracts become available

> You can enable Audit Trail for any user with the Marketing Cloud Security Administrator role. To enable Audit Trail, in Setup, select Security | Security Settings, and check Enable Audit Logging Data Collection. For Advanced Audit Trail, contact your account executive.

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in features for Auditing. Documentation text below

> Auditing
>
> > Auditing provides information about use of the system, which can be critical in diagnosing potential or real security issues. The Salesforce auditing features don't secure your organization by themselves; someone in your organization should do regular audits to detect potential abuse.
> >     To verify that your system is actually secure, you should perform audits to monitor for unexpected changes or usage trends.
>
> Record Modification Fields
>
> > All objects include fields to store the name of the user who created the record and who last modified the record. This provides some basic auditing information.
>
> Login History
>
> > You can review a list of successful and failed login attempts to your organization for the past six months. See Monitor Login History.
>
> Field History Tracking
>
> > You can also enable auditing for individual fields, which will automatically track any changes in the values of selected fields. Although auditing is available for all custom objects, only some standard objects allow field-level auditing. See Field History Tracking.
>
> Setup Audit Trail
>
> > Administrators can also view a Setup Audit Trail, which logs when modifications are made to your organization’s configuration. See Monitor Setup Changes.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_overview_auditing.htm&type=5

Comment: The original question is about the salesforce marketing cloud Audit Trial.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes this is possible we do it for a client.

We have a custom microsite and every time the customer logs in or updates their profile the AMP script uses the InsertData function and inserts a record into a logging table.

So if I login and update my preferences 5 times, I will have5 records in the logging DE.

This can easily be accessed by API using the standard DataExtensionObject API call which retrieves records from a table.

Comment: My question is not around Customer Logging in.. Its about the internl users (admins, managers etc.) ...  And the changes that I want to track are - 
- Who logged in with time
- Any changes that they made in the system (for e.g. any role changes, any BU created)
- Any data extension properties changed etc.

Comment: Ah ok - can see the confusion. no there is not a way I know of doing this